# how to know if UI is idle for X time?

Tags: java, android

I have a servery app. That ask questions from users.
What I want to do. If user did not do any thing with UI for the 1 mint... Then I must terminate the server.

What should I do for this?

I know ACTION_SCREEN_OFF. This event actually called when screen time out. That may be 30 mint? depend on user setting.
But let suppose user set time out for 30mint. and this event will call after 30 mint. But I want to know if UI is idle for 1 mint only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, I install a SCREEN_OFF broadcast listener within my code (not as a manifest entry, just a dynamic listener)... if it gets triggered, then I know the user has been idle as long as *their* definition of "too long".

Comment: can you please send me a link?

Comment: The very first link that appears when I google "screen_off receiver" seems rather relevant. http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/

Comment: This is not what I was looking for. You are not getting my point. This event actually called when screen time out. That may be 30 mint? depend on user setting.
But let suppose user set time out for 30mint. and this event will call after 30 mint. But I want to know if UI is idle for 1 mint only.

Comment: Android does not provide you what you're looking for exactly, so you need to be creative in finding a solution that fits your requirements. If SCREEN_OFF doesn't satisfy you, you could implement a combination of your own watchdog thread in conjunction with diligence in resetting this watchdog each time the user interacts with your app... just be sure to do something in your onPause() routine as well.